# Elements above JQuery accordion losing padding

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a jquery dialog that contains a jquery accordion among other things.  When I click the accordion headings to expand the different sections, the elements above the accordion lose their padding for the duration of the animation.  The result is that these elements shift to the left for the duration of the animation.  Below are the HTML/JS snippets in question.

Any thoughts?

HTML:

```
<div id="bodyDiv">
    <!-- Dialog -->
    <div id="patientPopup" title="Patient:" class="ui-widget">
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td class="AppointmentImage">
                    <img src="images/John-Petrucci-tn.jpg" alt="Patient Photo">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <b>Name:</b>&nbsp;Smith,&nbsp;Sally <b>DOB:</b>&nbsp;02/15/1984 <br />
                    <b>SSN:</b> 999-99-9999 <b>Address:</b> 123 Main St Nashville, TN 37204
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="width: 100%">
                    <!--Accordion-->
                    <div id="patientSummary">
                        <h3><a href="#">Encounters</a></h3>
                        <div>
                            <table class="PatientSummary">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>12/03/2011</th>
                                    <td>
                                        Office visit - this is text for the office visit.  some notes perhaps.
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>10/16/2011</th>
                                    <td>
                                        GYN visit - this is text to fill some space.
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <h3><a href="#">Alerts</a></h3>
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Diabetic</li>
                                <li>Due for FluShot</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <h3><a href="#">Labs/Radiology</a></h3>
                        <div>
                            <table style="vertical-align: text-top;">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Date</th>
                                    <th>Lab</th>
                                    <th>Result</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>12/03/2011</td>
                                    <td>Blood Panel</td>
                                    <td>N</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>12/03/2011</td>
                                    <td>Pregnancy Test</td>
                                    <td>Y</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>12/03/2011</td>
                                    <td>Blood Panel</td>
                                    <td>N</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>12/03/2011</td>
                                    <td>Pregnancy Test</td>
                                    <td>Y</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>12/03/2011</td>
                                    <td>Blood Panel</td>
                                    <td>N</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>12/03/2011</td>
                                    <td>Pregnancy Test</td>
                                    <td>Y</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <button id="showPatient">Show Patient</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#patientPopup").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 530,
        width: 600,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        open: function () {
            $("#patientSummary").accordion({
                fillSpace: true,
                autoHeight: true
            });
        }
    });

    $("#showPatient").button().click(
        function () {
            $("#patientPopup").dialog("open");
        }
    );
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple.  I ended up putting the image and text in a completely separate table than the accordion.

Never determined exactly why the top elements were losing their padding though...